# "sudo apt-get install xstlproc" returns "E:Unable to locate package xstlproc"

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-jessie, apt, debian

I'm following

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=196010#p1226096

to install a mosquitto server on Raspberry Pi 3 Model B

sudo apt-get install libc-ares-dev uuid-dev libwebsockets-dev libssl-dev xsltproc docbook-xsl

returns

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E:Unable to locate package xstlproc

I ran

sudo apt-get update

but running

sudo apt-get install xstlproc

still returns "E:Unable to locate package xstlproc"

Comment: You have a typo in the command. It should be `xsltproc`.

Comment: @Dirk - consider making this an answer.

Comment: @Seamus - not bothered. Someone stole it already and I really don't want to post a (sort of) duplicate answer

Comment: @Dirk: Understood. +1 for your comment then.

Answer (score 2):

You typed the package name wrong!

`sudo apt-get install xsltproc`

*not* `xstlproc`